# Complex Logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms

For what values of $p$ is the following valid?
$$\log(z^p) = p\log(z)$$
where 
$$\log(z) = \ln(|z|) + i[\arg(z)+2\pi n]$$
where $n$ is an integer.

I heard the expression above should not be valid for all p so I computed $\log((1+i)^n)$ and $\frac1n \log(1+i)$ for $n = \frac12$ and $2$, but got the same answer so I know I've done something incorrectly.

Comment: Your expression for $\log(z)$ is not a function.  You must choose a particular value for $n$. Then you can see where the problem lies.

Comment: As already noted, it depends on what you mean by ''log''. Is it a particular branch (which one?) or a multi-valued expression?